# Is $\sum_{i=1}^n i \in \Theta(n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Please help me understand on how to prove or disprove the following. I have been practicing and doing others which are ok, but with this sum, it is rather confusing.

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n i \in \Theta(n^2). $$

Comment: There is a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$. Apply the formula, and see what you get.

Comment: I have done it and got to a conclusion which most likely disproves.

Comment: What is your argument?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the computer science approach to answering this question.

On the one hand, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n n = n^2.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i \geq \sum_{i=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}^n \lfloor n/2 \rfloor = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lceil n/2 \rceil \geq (n/2)^2 - 1/4,
$$
since when $n$ is odd, $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lceil n/2 \rceil = (n/2-1/2)(n/2+1/2)$.